# OpenGL ES does not respond to touch after a while

Tags: ios, opengl-es, touch

I'm having a strange problem with my app. I'm using simple primitives in OpenGL ES 1.1 on iOS.

Here's what I have:

- A simple X-Y axes system
- A circle moving around the X-Y axes
- The circle can be moved around the 4 quadrants of the axes using touch

Here's how I'm moving the circle:

- Read the touch values from touchesMoved:withEvent: method
- glTranslatef the location of the circle based on the values retrieved from the above step

Here's my problem:

- The circle stays along with the touch for only slow movements. If the movement of the touch is fast the circle just does not respond to the movement OR loses track of the touch pretty soon.

Can someone suggest solutions!?

Answer (score 0):

try turning off multi-touch, if you have it on.
try removing openGL from the equation: just print the touch values with NSLog() - are they what you expect ?

Comment: I printed the touch co-ordinates and as long as I touch the display, I get values...